# Er: validation failure while creating a record with has_many association (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 tables one with has_many association and the other with belongs to. The models looks as follows:

map.rb:

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fields
end
```

field.rb:

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :map 
end
```

In the migration of field.rb, I have a field map_id.
But, when I try to create a map record by selecting some fields,

1 error prohibited this map from being saved.
There were problems with the following fields:

- Field is invalid

Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

**Edit**:
Adding schema

Schema will look something like this:

```
create_table "fields", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "map_id"
end

create_table "maps", force: :cascade do |t|
end
```

Comment: `class Field < < ActiveRecord::Base` is `< <` typo or actually it's written like that in `field.rb` file?

Comment: Can you post the schema here. Also, your model should be declared like `class Field  < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the model instance?

Comment: Hi @lusketeer it is just a typo.